# TerraformAzure: Call to Microsoft.SignalRService/SignalR failed. Error message: Invalid groupId"

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-signalr, azure-private-link

Trying to integrate my azure signalr service with a private endpoint, the below is the sample terraform code that I'm trying

```
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name                 = "${var.prefix}-signalr"
  location             = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id            = azurerm_subnet.endpoint.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "tfex-signalr-connection"
    is_manual_connection           = false
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_signalr.example.id
    subresource_names              = ["signalR"]
  }
}
```

When I'm running it, terraform init/plan is getting succeed , however while applying it failed with the below error

> creating Private Endpoint "signalr-02-privateendpoint" (Resource Group
> "app-services-windows-rg-01"):
> network.PrivateEndpointsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending
> request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="BadArgument"
> Message="Call to Microsoft.SignalRService/SignalR failed. Error
> message: Invalid groupId" Details=[]
>
> on ../../../common/private-endpoint/main.tf line 7, in resource
> "azurerm_private_endpoint" "generice_private_endpoint":    7: resource
> "azurerm_private_endpoint" "generice_private_endpoint" {

Already created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/11778) but want to reach other community members whether they faced this issue/ how to overcome this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my validation, you could change to use `signalr` instead of `signalR` in your code.

`subresource_names              = ["signalr"]`

[image]

Comment: wow its worked , the reason I put *R* i followed the official [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview#private-link-resource) I'm going to raise a PR to fix this issue so that it will not affect others. Thanks again !